# CakePHP HTML Helper: image within a link gets escaped?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Updating from Cake 1.2 to 1.3 and I have an image nested in a link element, both generated by the HTML helper. The nested image's markup is however escaped from `<` to `&gt;` ect. I know the HTML helper now escapes stuff by default, but I can't get it to change this behavior.

This is the code generating an example image link:

```
$html->link($html->image('icons/small/navigation-back.gif', array('alt'=>"Move Left", 'border'=>"0"))
,'#',array('id'=>'options_left'), array('escape'=>false))
```

I added the `array('escape'=>false)` bit from the official Cake documentation (part of the $options array), but I still get escaped image tags. Is the order set wrong or did more change than I'm aware of? The original code is straight from cake 1.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the third parameter is the options array:

```
$html->link($html->image('icons/small/navigation-back.gif', array('alt'=>"Move Left", 'border'=>"0"))
,'#',array('id'=>'options_left', 'escape'=>false))
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that second array WAS the options array.

Comment: tip: use a proper IDE with code completion. then those mistakes can and will be avoided :)

Comment: @mark my IDE does...but not for methods included via Cake models or controllers it seems.

Comment: my script works for phpdesigner. the trick was to use the app helper as scope. but maybe the view class would work, too: http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/code-completion/