# CakePHP: How to use HTML entities in button titles using Form Helper

Tags: cakephp, html-entities

I'd like to use a checkmark as the text for a button. The entity I want is `&#x2713;` but when I put that in as the text for the button using the Form Helper, it always converts the leading ampersand into `&amp;` so that the text shows but not the entity.

Here's how I'm creating the button:

```
echo $this->Form->button(
    '&#x2713;', 
    array(
        'type' => 'submit', 
        'id' => $checklistItem['ChecklistItem']['id'], 
        'escape' => 'false'
    )
);
```

and the generated HTML looks like this:

`<button type="submit" id="1">&amp;#x2713;</button>`

which obviously doesn't render the entity.

I've tried it by setting `'escape' => 'true'` but that has not effect at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Never ever use true/false as strings ('true'/'false'). The only other valid representation is 0/1. You completely inverse the boolean state of false to true this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to escape it false, it is by default escaped to false.

```
  echo $this->Form->button('&#x2713;',  
          array(
               'type' => 'submit', 
               'id' => $checklistItem['ChecklistItem']['id']
           )
  );
```

Comment: I think you missed something. Your button looks exactly like the one in the OP. :/

Comment: i could not understand what you want to say. what is meant by `like the one in the OP. :`

Comment: Your answer is exactly like the code in the question, just harder to read because you removed all the line breaks.

Comment: my answer is not exactly as the question, if you execute my code, then you will see that it is a solution, which shows tick mark, which is required by the questioner. As far as line breaks are concerned, i have reformatted code.

Comment: Wow. That code works, but it is exactly what I started with several hours ago. I only added the 'escape' thing when it failed to render correctly. I can see it in my local file history that it was exactly the same... bizarre. Well, it works now! Thanks!

Comment: @iopener, you were using `'escape' => 'false'`, while it should be `'escape' => false`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your escape to the third element of the button:

```
echo $this->Form->button(
    '&#x2713;', 
    array(
        'type' => 'submit',
        'id' => $checklistItem['ChecklistItem']['id'], 
    ),
    array('escape' => 'false')
);
```

Also, this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263680/cakephp-html-helper-image-within-a-link-gets-escaped).

Comment: button function can have only two parameters, check here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::button. But you are passing three parameters here.

Comment: Yeah, the form parameters are different from the html parameters. It was one of the first things I checked out.

Comment: What version of cake are you using. This code works in v2.3.0 stable.

Comment: Using version 2.2.0. According to comments above, the => 'false' syntax won't work either. Are you saying that this parameter has been added in 2.3.0 and that it will parse 'false' as the boolean value false as well?